# How to convert for loop to STL for_each statement

Tags: c++, stl, parallel-processing

I would like to convert my for loop to STL std::for_each loop.

```
 bool CMyclass::SomeMember()
 {
    int ii;
        for(int i=0;i<iR20;i++)
            {
              ii=indexR[i];
              ishell=static_cast<int>(R[ii]/xStep);
              theta=atan2(data->pPOS[ii*3+1], data->pPOS[ii*3]);
              al2[ishell] += massp*cos(fm*theta);
            }
 }
```

Actually I was planning to use parallel STL from g++4.4

```
 g++ -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL -fopenmp
```

which is allow to run code in parallel without changes if the code is written in standard STL library.

Comment: Why not simply `#pragma omp parallel for` before the for?

Comment: +1 stephan, though tje `al2[ishell]` **+=** needs a reduction clause or atomic barrier. Not sure how this would translate into STL parallel.

Comment: Yes one of the solutions will be "#pragma omp parallel for" but always before each for one need to consider shared and private variables. which is always one of the sources of errors.

Comment: @peterchen: agree, reduction might be necessary (unless `ishell` takes each value only once).

Comment: Btw, C++0x will likely also contain lambdas, which can be used to simplify the code: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#lambda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to seperate out the loop body into a seperate function or functor; I've assumed all the undeclared variables are member variables.

```
void CMyclass::LoopFunc(int ii)  {
    ishell=static_cast<int>(R[ii]/xStep);
    theta=atan2(data->pPOS[ii*3+1],
    data->pPOS[ii*3]);
    al2[ishell] += massp*cos(fm*theta);
}

bool CMyclass::SomeMember()  { 
    std::for_each(&indexR[0],&indexR[iR20],std::tr1::bind(&CMyclass::LoopFunc,std::tr1::ref(*this));
}
```

Comment: Nice!! this concept is the best. Thanks!

Comment: Is this solution thread safe? I would assume not. If the parallel `for_each` splits the loop into different threads, all of them will be accessing the same member attributes without any kind of protection.

Comment: He'd need to be careful about thread safety - his original code didn't make clear what variables were locals and which were member variables. Writing to index i and index i+1 in different threads should be safe for an array of ints shouldn't it?

Comment: If you read from the member from different threads you don't need to worry. For writing probably I need a lock.

Answer (score 1):

```
class F {
   public:
   void operator()(int ii) {
              ishell=static_cast<int>(R[ii]/xStep);
              theta=atan2(data->pPOS[ii*3+1], data->pPOS[ii*3]);
              al2[ishell] += massp*cos(fm*theta);
   } 
   F(int[] r): //and other parameters should also be passed into the constructor
      r_(r) {}
   void:
   int[] r_; // refers to R[ii] array
   // and other parameters should also be stored
};

F f(R); // pass other parameters too  
for_each(&indexR[0], &indexR[iR20], f);
```

However it might not be a good idea to use this "automatic parallelization" since you need to keep in mind the grainsize of each parallel computation -- I am not sure how well the compiler takes the grain size into account.

Comment: This looks good, but imagine I have several loops in the SomeMember() function and we need to define Class like functors for the every loop.

Comment: Yes. That's the C++ way of functional programming. If you're gonna do this, you may as well use Intel TBB and use parallel_for for parallelization (TBB is the way I prefer).

Comment: Yes TBB well designed, but I am a researcher, I prefer GPL software.

Comment: Not sure why you prefer GPL. The TBB license (GPL with runtime exception) should be compatible with GPL (although I am not a lawyer and cannot make a reliable statement). Or do you mean you prefer open-source? Then, that's a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just separate cycle body into functor and assume that it will be paralellised because you have too many dependencies inside cycle body. 
Cycle will be able to run in parallel only if you have no global arrays or pointers. If you provide full function body then we can think how to change it to parallel version.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert the loop body into a function or functor.  There are a lot of undeclared variables in there, so I can't easily tell how to separate out the loop body.  Here's a stab at it:

```
class DoStuff
{
  int* R;
  int xStep;
  Data* data;
  double massp;
  double fm;
  double* al2;
public:
  DoStuff(int* R_, int xStep_, Data* data_, double massp_, double fm_, double* al2_) :
    R(R_), xStep(xStep_), data(data_), massp(massp_), fm(fm_), al2(al2_) {}

  void operator()(int ii)
  {
     int ishell = static_cast<int>(R[ii]/xStep);
     double theta = atan2(data->pPOS[ii*3+1], data->pPOS[ii*3]);
     al2[ishell] += massp*cos(fm*theta);
  }
};

for_each(indexR, indexR+iR20, DoStuff(R, xStep, data, massp, fm, al2));
```

Comment: When using initialisation list, you don't have to rename arguments. I.e. `R(R)` etc. will work just fine.